# Use rounding function after parsing data from a file

Tags: php, c++, c, parsing, rounding

I have quite a few html files with several  links in it. E.g.

```
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.7948205&amp;longitude=-72.12729890000003" >location 1</a></div>
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.9020418&amp;longitude=-72.07979440000002" >location 2</a></div>
```

I want to round the longitude values to 6 decimal places. E.g.

```
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.7948205&amp;longitude=-72.127299" >location 1</a></div>
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.9020418&amp;longitude=-72.079794" >location 2</a></div>
```

I'm a noob when it comes to file parsing and don't know if this is possible. I would appreciate any pointers and guidance.

Comment: Do you have a language preference?

Comment: Hi @Derek - Thanks for your quick response. I am comfortable with PHP, C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some PHP code that would do it:

```
$str = '<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.7948205&amp;longitude=-72.12729890000003" >location 1</a></div>
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.9020418&amp;longitude=-72.07979440000002" >location 2</a></div>
<div><a href="/location/?latitude=41.9020418&amp;longitude=-72.07979440000002" >location 3</a></div>';

$arr = explode("\n", $str);

$decimalPlaces = 5;

foreach ($arr as &$line) {
     if (preg_match("/latitude=(.*?)&amp;longitude=(.*?)\"/", $line, $matches)) {
         $latitudeApprox = round($matches[1], $decimalPlaces);
         $longitudeApprox = round($matches[2], $decimalPlaces);
         $line = preg_replace("/latitude=.*?&amp;longitude=.*?\"/", "latitude=$latitudeApprox&amp;longitude=$longitudeApprox\"", $line);
    }
}

$str = implode("\n", $arr);
echo $str;
```

Note that the regex for pulling out the longitude is not very robust.  It assumes you never have a case like this, for example:

```
<a href="/location/?latitude=41.7948205&amp;longitude=-72.12729890000003&amp;SOMETHING+ELSE+HERE" >...</a>
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver. This works great! No I don't have any cases for another query parameter after longitude..

Comment: Is this easy to modify if I want to round both latitude and longitude at the same time? to say 5 decimal places?

Comment: Sure, I updated the code to pull out both longitude and latitude.  You can change the value of $decimalPlaces to whatever precision you need.

Comment: Perfect! Much appreciated!